# What is the easiest way to return the first set of linq query properties as optional strings?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

What is the easiest way to return the first set of linq query properties as optional strings or covert from type anonymous to (string?, string?)? The below doesn't work because of the anonymous object.

```
private (string? HotemName, string? TransportationName) Get3rdPartyHotelTranporationNames(int customerID, int supplierID, System.DateTime? startDate, System.DateTime? endDate) 
{

    var x = (from res in reservations
             join trans in _unitOfWork.tbl_reservations on res.id_pk equals transRes.id
             where trans.status == 4
             select new
             {
                 HotemName = res.Name,
                 TransportationName = trans.Name
             }).Take(1).Single();

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous type is not the same as tuple.

> [Anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
>   define a type first. The type name is generated by the compiler and is
>   not available at the source code level. The type of each property is
>   inferred by the compiler.
>
> [C# tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) are types that you define using a lightweight syntax.
>   The advantages include a simpler syntax, rules for conversions based
>   on number (referred to as cardinality) and types of elements, and
>   consistent rules for copies, equality tests, and assignments. As a
>   tradeoff, tuples do not support some of the object-oriented idioms
>   associated with inheritance.

Also, you can't return anonymous type from function. In your case you should returns new tuple from LINQ like in the code below:

```
private (string? HotemName, string? TransportationName) Get3rdPartyHotelTranporationNames(int customerID, int supplierID, System.DateTime? startDate, System.DateTime? endDate) 
{
    return (from res in reservations
             join trans in _unitOfWork.tbl_reservations on res.id_pk equals transRes.id
             where trans.status == 4
             select (res.Name, trans.Name)
             ).Take(1).Single();
}
```